# Leaflet.draw multi-coloured polyline segments

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet.draw to draw a polyline, with the user doing all the point and clicking (i.e. the points do not come from a database). I want the lines between the individual vertices to be different colours. I have tried setting the style.color property in the various events leaflet exposes (eg. CREATED) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to draw each line segment as a separate polyline, with its own colour, then group together the segments using a [FeatureGroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup) so that you can manipulate them together. e.g.

```
# Place a two-segment line on the map.
var segment1 = L.polyline(latlngs1, {color: 'red'});
var segment2 = L.polyline(latlngs2, {color: 'blue'});
var multiSegment = L.featureGroup([segment1, segment2])
    .addTo(map);
```

After the FeatureGroup has been created and placed on the map, you can still add additional segments (they show on the map straight away):

```
# Add another segment to the group later
var segment3 = L.polyline(latlngs3, {color: 'green'});
multiSegment.addLayer(segment3);
```

Using the FeatureGroup, you can bind event listeners, popups, etc. to the group as a whole, or do manipulations like adding/removing from the map in one go.

```
# Bind a popup to the whole group
multiSegment.bindPopup('Hello world!');
```